# pspice olb files

Tags: spice

Are there any good places to look for these files? I've been googling for a few hours but haven't found anything substantial.

Also if anyone knows where to find a vpwl off the top of their head any help would be much appreciated.

Just in case, it's referenced on the bottom of the second page [in this link](http://www.ee.ucla.edu/~jjudy/classes/ee100/pspice/tutorials/PSpice%20v9.2%20Tutorial%20Part%20II%20-%20Transient%20Analysis.pdf).

Comment: A piece-wise linear source (PWL, not LWP as in your question) is a standard, included, source component in spice.  Look under voltage sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [OrCADexchange Yahoo! Group](http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/OrCADexchange/) for community generated models. If your vendor publishes models you can convert them into OrCAD's format with a tool such as [UltraLibrarian](http://www.accelerated-designs.com).